# Can't get a newline with scriptsize

Tags: line-breaking

This is what I wrote in the editor:

```
\begin{array}{c}
{\scriptsize mx-3x=2(2-x) \par
First: }
\end{array}
```

```
\begin{array}{c}
{\scriptsize mx-3x=2(2-x) \newline
First: }
\end{array}
```

It doesn't work in the way I expected, I am using the web editor by the way.https://www.latexlive.com/

Comment: use \\ to get a newline

Comment: you can not use size change commands like `\scriptsize` in math mode

Comment: Off-topic: `\scriptsize` is a text-mode command. Since an `array` environment must occur in math mode, I think you should be writing `\scriptstyle`, not `\scriptsize`.

Answer (score 3):

Inside an `array` you should use `\\` to get into a new row. A `c` column can't contain line breaks, because it's in horizontal mode only (but you could nest something that is multi-line, for instance another `array`, doesn't make much sense here).

But `\\` is in another group, you would get an error if you just switched out your `\newline` for `\\` (because you opened a group earlier).

So you should just put a `\scriptsize` into the second row as well (no need to put an explicit group around it, the cells form them for you). And as per @Mico's comment: `\scriptstyle` is probably what you want.

```
\begin{array}{c}
  \scriptstyle mx-3x=2(2-x) \\
  \mbox{\scriptsize First:}
\end{array}
```

Also to get a correct "First" appearance (that's text, not F*i*r*s*t), you should wrap it in `\mbox` or `\text`.

Comment: @Mico I was already editing the answer (roughly 10 seconds after I posted it), but then got sidetracked and didn't hit the save button... :P